# Highcharts custom visuals with Data binding PowerBI

Tags: highcharts, data-binding, powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals, data-mapping

Bharath R created a nice [example](https://bharathonsqlserver.blogspot.com/2019/08/to-add-highcharts-in-power-bi-as-custom.html) of how to create a highcharts custom visual for PowerBI. However, no data binding has been applied yet. For the highcharts line diagram below I would like to use variables instead of hard coded values. So that it is possible to apply data binding.

Here you can find the [example](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqNwu3Py13a9iDuRGYTlVBTYyQBD?e=lVNQWr) PowerBI file that contains the highcharts custom visual and the data that needs to be loaded into the custom visual. In this file I made two data tables. I don't have a preference for one of the two data tables. The important thing is that the data is structured in such a way that it is easiest to load in the highcharts visual.

Example code (visual.ts)

```
"use strict";

import "core-js/stable";
import "./../style/visual.less";
import powerbi from "powerbi-visuals-api";
import VisualConstructorOptions = powerbi.extensibility.visual.VisualConstructorOptions;
import VisualUpdateOptions = powerbi.extensibility.visual.VisualUpdateOptions;
import IVisual = powerbi.extensibility.visual.IVisual;
import EnumerateVisualObjectInstancesOptions = powerbi.EnumerateVisualObjectInstancesOptions;
import VisualObjectInstance = powerbi.VisualObjectInstance;
import DataView = powerbi.DataView;
import VisualObjectInstanceEnumerationObject = powerbi.VisualObjectInstanceEnumerationObject;

import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import * as Exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting';

import { VisualSettings } from "./settings";
export class Visual implements IVisual {
private target: HTMLElement;
private settings: VisualSettings;

    constructor(options: VisualConstructorOptions) {
        console.log('Visual constructor', options);
        this.target = options.element;
    }

    public update(options: VisualUpdateOptions) {
        this.settings = Visual.parseSettings(options && options.dataViews && options.dataViews[0]);
        console.log('Visual update', options);
        var optionMain=this.target;

        /**
         * Code to add highcharts
         */

        Highcharts.chart(optionMain.id, {

            title: {
                text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
            },

            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
            },

            xAxis: {
                categories: ['2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016', '2017']
            },

            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Number of Employees'
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle'
            },

            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    label: {
                        connectorAllowed: false
                    }
                }
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Installation',
                data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175],
                type: undefined
            }, {
                name: 'Manufacturing',
                data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434],
                type: undefined
            }, {
                name: 'Sales & Distribution',
                data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387],
                type: undefined
            }, {
                name: 'Project Development',
                data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227],
                type: undefined
            }, {
                name: 'Other',
                data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111],
                type: undefined
            }],

            responsive: {
                rules: [{
                    condition: {
                        maxWidth: 500
                    },
                    chartOptions: {
                        legend: {
                            layout: 'horizontal',
                            align: 'center',
                            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }

        });



    }

    private static parseSettings(dataView: DataView): VisualSettings {
        return VisualSettings.parse(dataView) as VisualSettings;
    }

    /**
     * This function gets called for each of the objects defined in the capabilities files and allows you to select which of the
     * objects and properties you want to expose to the users in the property pane.
     *
     */
    public enumerateObjectInstances(options: EnumerateVisualObjectInstancesOptions): VisualObjectInstance[] | VisualObjectInstanceEnumerationObject {
        return VisualSettings.enumerateObjectInstances(this.settings || VisualSettings.getDefault(), options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a question somewhere? If yes, then I have surely missed it. If you have a problem with the Highcharts library or the charts please describe them, so we could help with that.

Comment: Hi Kacper, The question is to dynamically load the data (json format) into the custom highcharts visual. This can be done by applying so-called data binding. This is explained here: https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-visuals/docs/concepts/dataviewmappings/ However, I don't know how to get this working so I am asking if someone can help me. Hopefully the question is now more clear for you.

Comment: By any chance do you have working code that adds HighCharts to Power BI?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the differences between your link and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/visuals/dataview-mappings. It seems that  microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-visuals/docs/concepts/… is deprecated and some features and synthax have change.

In your example I don't see your definitions in **dataViewMappings**.

[image]

Here what happen when I follow exactly the steps indicated in the two links (not the deprecated) and here the result, dynamically loaded. Try to follow this tutorial and come back if your problem is still present.

Comment: Hi Boom1207,i have already tried the link from above. But with the help of this document it is still not possible for me to apply the data binding. That is why I'm asking if someone can send a sample code in which the data binding for highcharts has been applied. Still appreciating your help!

Comment: Did you figure out how to use real data with HighCharts visuals?